# Why are multiple calls to calloc crashing my app?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I have a function that initializes a struct that contains nested structs and arrays.
While initializing the struct I have multiple calls to `calloc`.

Refer to code bellow:

```
typedef struct
{
    int length;
    uint8_t *buffer;
} buffer_a;

typedef struct
{
    int length;
    uint8_t *buffer;
    int *second_buffer_size;
    uint8_t **second_buffer;
} buffer_b;

typedef struct
{
    int max_length;
    buffer_a *buffer_in;
    buffer_b *buffer_out;
} state_struct;


state_struct *init(int size, int elements) {
    size_t struct_size = sizeof(state_struct);
    state_struct *s = (state_struct*) calloc(struct_size, struct_size);

    log("Building state with length %d", size);

    s->max_length = size;

    size_t buffer_in_size = s->max_length * sizeof(buffer_a);
    s->buffer_in = (buffer_a*) calloc(buffer_in_size, buffer_in_size);

    size_t buffer_out_size = s->max_length * sizeof(buffer_b);
    s->buffer_out = (buffer_b*) calloc(buffer_out_size, buffer_out_size);

    log("Allocated memory for both buffers structs");

    for (int i = 0; i < s->max_length; ++i) {
        size_t buf_size = elements * sizeof(uint8_t);

        s->buffer_in[i].buffer = (uint8_t*) calloc(buf_size, buf_size);
        s->buffer_in[i].length = -1;
        log(s, "Allocated memory for in buffer");

        s->buffer_out[i].buffer = (uint8_t*) calloc(buf_size, buf_size);
        s->buffer_out[i].length = -1;
        log(s, "Allocated memory for out buffer");

        size_t inner_size = elements * elements * sizeof(uint8_t);
        size_t inner_second_buffer_size = elements * sizeof(int);    
        s->buffer_out[i].second_buffer = (uint8_t**) calloc(inner_size, inner_size);
        s->buffer_out[i].second_buffer_size = (int*) calloc(inner_second_buffer_size, inner_second_buffer_size);
        log(s, "Allocated memory for inner buffer");
    }

    return s;
}
```

Logs just before the for loop are printed but the program crashes and the first log statement inside the loop does not get printed out.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `(uint8_t**) calloc(inner_size, inner_size);` looks suspicious. As there's a double pointer but not sizeof pointer involved in size calculation

Comment: Maybe not part of the problem, but `state_struct *s = (state_struct*) calloc(struct_size, struct_size);` is also suspicious: `calloc()` takes a size (which you mention) plus a count of items, and this looks like it's asking for much more memory than required. You probably mean `state_struct *s = calloc(1, struct_size);`, and no cast is needed.

Comment: Your function does not return anything.

Comment: @KamilCuk missed that while copying the code. Added it now

Comment: This is totally not how `calloc` works. Have you read the documentation? Have you seen a working example of code with `calloc`?

Answer (score 1):

So this may not be an answer to your question, but here goes:
When I ran this code (on Ubuntu, gcc 7.4), and replaced all the `log` functions with `printf`, it finished succesfuly. I suspect the problem might be in the way you use the log function. You specify that it works up until the first log call inside the loop. You didn't specify what the `log` function does, or whether it is a function or just a macro wrapper for `printf`, but you call it in a different manner inside the loop - the first parameter is `*state_struct` rather than a format string.

Also, the way you call `calloc` seems to be semantically incorrect. The first parameter should be the number of blocks of second parameter size you want to allocate (presumably 1 in this case)